# using common methods among multiple classes

Tags: asp.net

I have a couple of class files in C#. I want to write a method that could be used in all the classes. For example, I am trying to write the method that returns the number of rows from the database table, and I need this in multiple times, so thought of writing a single method to share among all the classes. I thought it would be easy with the use of namespace. But when I add namespace in all the class files, it gives error stating "CONTROL NAME is not present in current context". From the internet search I came to the conclusion that I also need to add the namespace in xxx.designer.cs files. Is it correct? I tried to find the designer.cs files but could not, and in one of the solution it was stated that designer.cs file is created during compile time. If so how to add the namespace on designer.cs file.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a static class and this function that classes need to share has to be a static member.

This function can now be called from anywhere.

```
static class Helper
{
    public static string Calculate(int myVariable) 
    {
        //do some common calculation
    }
    //...
}
```

If these classes have common data members and you need to share a common function, you can consider using a base class. All common functionality and common data members would go into the base class, and by merit of inheriting that class, all your sub classes would be able to call this function.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Static class and create static member functions into that. You need not to create instance of the class in this case and you can directly call member function using class name.